# Determine the operator norm of the following function

Tags: functional-analysis

I have given a function $L: R^2 \to R^2$ , defined as $L(v)= A*v$ where $A$ is a $2\times2$ Matrix \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}. Determine the operatornorm and show that a $v$ in $R^2$ exists, such that $||v||_2=1$ and $||L(v)||_2 = ||L||_{operator}$.

I have been trying to solve this all day, we mentioned operator norms very briefly in the lecture and now we are asked to solve this. I know the definitions of all the above mentioned things, however I cannot seem to put them into practice, how do you determine the operator norm and then what could possibly be a way to start to prove the second part of the exercise?
We haven't still learned any sort of Eigenvalues or Eigenvectors or anything like that.

Thank you in Advance for your help!

Annalisa

Edit: I am listing here the things I know about the operator norm but cannot put into practice.
I know that it is defined
$||L||_op = sup ||x||_2  for ||x||_1 \leq 1$
and I know that in the case of continuous functions it holds $||Lx||_2 \leq ||L||_{operator} *||x||_1$

Comment: Would be good that you use Latex to type your question as recommended in the site. In particular to understand what the matrix $A$ is.

Comment: Welcome to MSE . The prof must have told you something to help you solve the problems. List all things you know about operator norm (even in the post it wouldn't be a  bad idea). Also you should try to use Mathjax for equations.

Comment: hello, i did as you guys suggested